# How to deploy a smart contract using CREATE2 with truffle?

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, create2, deploy

How can I deploy a new smart contract using `CREATE2` upcode ([EIP-1014](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1014.md)) with truffle?